# When Select Change Background Images Change

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Hello I have a problem with html Select...When user will click one of the Value then background images have to change and appear a new Select and the old Select will disappear. I tried many things but it wasn't work...help me out please...

Here is the code:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
var header = $('body');

function SelectElement(valueToSelect)
{    
    var element = document.getElementById('test');
    element.value = '1';
}
$(function() {
  $('.test').click(function() {
    var backgrounds = new Array(
    'url(images/Main/1.png)'
  , 'url(images/Main/2.jpg)'
  , 'url(images/Main/3.jpg)'
  , 'url(images/Main/4.jpg)'
  , 'url(images/Main/5.jpg)'
  , 'url(images/Main/6.jpg)'
  , 'url(images/Main/7.jpg)'
  , 'url(images/Main/8.jpg)'
  , 'url(images/Main/9.jpg)'
  , 'url(images/Main/10.jpg)'
);
  });
}); 
var current = 0;

function nextBackground() {
    current++;
    current = current % backgrounds.length;
    header.css('background-image', backgrounds[current]);
}
setInterval(nextBackground, 6000);

header.css('background-image', backgrounds[0]);
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
<center>
<div id="black">
<div style="margin-top:22%;margin-bottom:-22%;">
<form name="test">
<select id="test" name="test">
<option value="Select Season" selected="selected" disabled="disabled">Select Season..</option>
<option value="1" onclick="function()">Season 1</option>
<option value="Season 2">Season 2</option>
<option value="Season 3">Season 3</option>
<option value="Season 4">Season 4</option>
</select>
</form>
```

Comment: Why is the first image a png and all others are jpg?

Comment: Not the issue, but `$(document).ready(function(){});` and `$(function(){})` do the same thing, there is no reason to nest them as you have here

Comment: `var backgrounds` is local (in scope) to where it is defined -- click handler -- and is not visible to the callback of the outer DOM ready. **Thus `background[0]` is undefined**.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question is not entirely clear. The first (hidden) snippit below will set the background to the image that is stored in an array at the same index as the selected option and then show a different select box as you asked. But I get the feeling the second (showing) snippet is what you really need.

To better help you, please edit your question to include answers to the below questions:

1. Should the timer begin changing the backgrounds as soon as the
   page loads?
2. What should happen when the first select box is changed
3. what should happen when the second select box is changed?
4. are we talking about the page body's background or some  other div, or does each event control the background for a different div?
5. Are all of the pictures pulled from the same array or does each event have a different pool of source inmages?

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  
var header = $('body');

function SelectElement(valueToSelect)
{    
    var element = document.getElementById('test');
    element.value = '1';
}

  $('#test').change(function() {
        
    // I did this with 4 images for testing, add as many as you like in yours
        var backgrounds = ['url(http://stylonica.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/03/Nature___Seasons___Spring__038259_.jpg)'
  , 'url(http://hd.wallpaperswide.com/thumbs/summer_holiday-t2.jpg)'
  , 'url(http://www.grandfather.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/08/fall-road.jpg)'
  , 'url(http://hooptricks.org/wp-content/uploads/2014/01/road-winter.jpg)'];
     
    // get index of selected option
    // -1 is to account for the disabled fist option acting as a placeholder
    var cur =  $(this)[0].selectedIndex -1; 
    
    // set the image to the background
    header.css('background-image', backgrounds[cur]);
                           
    //hide the first select and show the second
    $('#fisrtSelDiv').hide();
    $('#secondSelDiv').show();
    
    
  });


/*

// I commented the below out as it doesnt appear to be related to your question
// if you need the select to begin a timer that changes the backgrounds peridically
// please edit your question with more detail

var current = 0;

function nextBackground() {
    current++;
    current = current % backgrounds.length;
    header.css('background-image', backgrounds[current]);
}
setInterval(nextBackground, 6000);
header.css('background-image', backgrounds[0]);

*/
  
  
});
```

```css
#secondSelDiv{
  display:none;
  
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="black">
<div style="margin-top:22%;margin-bottom:-22%;">
  
<div id="fisrtSelDiv">
<form name="test">
<select id="test" name="test">
<option value="" selected="selected" disabled="disabled">Select Season..</option>
<option value="Season 1">Season 1</option>
<option value="Season 2">Season 2</option>
<option value="Season 3">Season 3</option>
<option value="Season 4">Season 4</option>
</select>
</form>
</div>
  
<div id="secondSelDiv">
<form name="test2">
<select id="test2" name="test">
<option value="" selected="selected" disabled="disabled">Select something else...</option>
<option value="something 1">A thing</option>
<option value="something 2">A second thing</option>
<option value="something 3">Something else</option>
<option value="something 4">Another thing</option>
</select>
</form>
</div>
```

**It seems more likely that you want the image rotation to start when the user selects an option then show the next select, if so this'll get you there:**

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  
var header = $('body');
  
  
var current = 0;       
// I did this with 4 images for testing, add as many as you like in yours
var backgrounds = ['url(http://stylonica.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/03/Nature___Seasons___Spring__038259_.jpg)'
  , 'url(http://hd.wallpaperswide.com/thumbs/summer_holiday-t2.jpg)'
  , 'url(http://www.grandfather.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/08/fall-road.jpg)'
  , 'url(http://hooptricks.org/wp-content/uploads/2014/01/road-winter.jpg)'];
     

function SelectElement(valueToSelect)
{    
    var element = document.getElementById('test');
    element.value = '1';
}

  $('#test').change(function() {
    
    // set the first image to the background
    header.css('background-image', backgrounds[0]);
    
    //start the timer
    setInterval(nextBackground, 6000);
                           
    //hide the first select and show the second
    $('#fisrtSelDiv').hide();
    $('#secondSelDiv').show();
    
    
  });





function nextBackground() {
    current++;
    current = current % backgrounds.length;
    header.css('background-image', backgrounds[current]);
}

  
  
});
```

```css
#secondSelDiv{
  display:none;
  
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="black">
<div style="margin-top:22%;margin-bottom:-22%;">
  
<div id="fisrtSelDiv">
<form name="test">
<select id="test" name="test">
<option value="" selected="selected" disabled="disabled">Select Season..</option>
<option value="Season 1">Season 1</option>
<option value="Season 2">Season 2</option>
<option value="Season 3">Season 3</option>
<option value="Season 4">Season 4</option>
</select>
</form>
</div>
  
<div id="secondSelDiv">
<form name="test2">
<select id="test2" name="test">
<option value="" selected="selected" disabled="disabled">Select something else...</option>
<option value="something 1">A thing</option>
<option value="something 2">A second thing</option>
<option value="something 3">Something else</option>
<option value="something 4">Another thing</option>
</select>
</form>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you very much :D but I need a timer to background change and at the first select I need backgrounds too..after the user select season then it will do that thing it does..and after that a third one please help me out...thanks again..!! :D

Comment: @GotSeriesTyrion Ok, so we're on the right track. But it sounds like you want to manipulate the background after several different events. Check out the edit to my answer above. Provide this information as an edit to your question and Ill help you get to what you need.

Answer (score 1):

There are several issues with your current code - `test` is an id, not a class, so the selector is `#test` instead of `.test`

The array containing the images is not accessible from the function `nextBackground()`, as this array is defined in the function attached to the click event.
To be accessible for other function, it can be declared global.
I guess you don't want to change the image when select is clicked, but when an option is selected.
Maybe you want to change the background image according to the selected option - in this case it's possible to attach a function to the `change()` event of the select
and select the image from the background array with the index according to
the option value e.g. like this:

```
$('#test').change(function () {
    header.css('background-image', backgrounds[$(this).val() -1]);
});
```

In addition, in your current code you call the function `nextBackground()` which
cycles through all background images.
I've just commented this out in the example [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/50vdn3ns/)

Remaining question is how the new select that you want to display instead of the old select when an option is selected should be different from the old select, maybe
you can add this information to your question.

Comment: since your values start at 1 but arrays are 0 based, should this not be `$(this).val() - 1` ?

Comment: @DelightedD0D Thanks for mentioning, adjusted.